# What is the difference between a model and a bunch of stacked layers in TF 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

So, I can create my model by subclassing Keras layers and models, like this:

```
class CNN(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CNN, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (4, 4), padding='same')
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, ip):
        x = self.l1(ip)
        op = self.l2(x)
        return op
```

How does this differ from

```
mymodel = Model(input = inputs, output= outputs)
```

I mean, I know some differences, like the model above has the attribute mymodel.input but when I ask for this attribute for a model defined by subclassing it throws this error:

> AttributeError: Layer cnn is not connected, no input to return.

that's just one difference, so, what makes them different and how to flesh out the first model to make have all the attributes of a model defined in the classical way? More precisely, as in the title: what is the difference between a bunch of stacked layers and a model ?

Answer (score 1):

From a software perspective `Model` is a unique python class, likewise as the various layers ( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model is from TF 1.13 documentation ). Like for any python class there are unique methods, so is for `Model`.

How the `Model` class integrates the various layers **logically** is in the source code of the Model class that is in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py ( for TF 1.13, source code for TF 2.0 is very likely similar, to easier find search for `class Model` with Ctrl+F in the file )

Comment: Why does a model constructed with subclassing throws an error when asked for its input or output attribute?

Comment: Normally a similar error is thrown when the model is not set up accurately, see i.e. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2060

Comment: Even if specify an input, I get the same error. I usually do that in the build method following construction.  Additionally, model.output throws the same error. Evenmore, the model cannot be serialized and saved. So many problems with custom-made NNs.

Comment: it is possible that the errors emerge from the fact that you did not create an instance of your subclassed model, see https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing chapter **Saving Subclassed Models** and there is still the possibility that there are errors in the setup of the model so the model will not even build

Comment: I read that article. It says it cannot be serialized. You can only save weights but not entire model if it is custom-made.

Comment: the important part is *First of all, a subclassed model that has never been used cannot be saved.* there are also no inputs and outputs etc. read chapter **Saving Subclassed Models**